# clustering text test cases for prioritization

Tags: r, nlp, k-means

I am trying to cluster manually documented test cases so that they can be prioritized and repetitive test cases can be eliminated. Test cases which are similar can be grouped together and then running a few test cases a single cluster would give an idea of how the other test cases in the same cluster would perform with some confidence level so that we can move on to running test cases in other clusters rather running similar test which adds little value to the quality of the application.

The test cases are general text based with little structure and are written manually. Thus I am thinking of an approach of first to do some text analysis of the test case description to put some structure and then apply a clustering algorithm.

Please suggest how to proceed with this.